# Get all comments associated with a specific page ID (comment_post_ID)

Tags: comments

I try to get all comments of a specific post, but it is not working like the way I do want. I use `$assignment->ID` to get all comments for a specific page ID. Even when I change `$assignment->ID` to `101` it is not working and he still shows all the comments of all posts.

```
foreach($assignments as $assignment) {

    echo $assignment->post_title;
                                
    $args = array(
        'number' => 0,
        'status' => 'approve',
        // shows all comments, but it shouldn't
        'comment_post_ID' => $assignment->ID
    );
                                
    $comments = get_comments( $args );
                                
    if ( $comments ) {
        foreach ( $comments as $comment )   {
            echo '<li>';
            echo $comment->comment_content;
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }

}
```

I think I miss an important `$arg`, but I'm not sure which one. It doesn't matter what I do, all comments are showing up everytime..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on developer documents of `get_comments` functions, it is using args like `WP_Comment_Query::__construct` Method which is accepts `post_id` in the argument's array. So, the code will be like:

```
foreach($assignments as $assignment) {

    echo $assignment->post_title;
                                
    $args = array(
        'number' => 0,
        'status' => 'approve',
        // shows all comments, but it shouldn't
        'post_id' => $assignment->ID
    );
                                
    $comments = get_comments( $args );
                                
    if ( $comments ) {
        foreach ( $comments as $comment )   {
            echo '<li>';
            echo $comment->comment_content;
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }

}
```

Links:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_comment_query/__construct/

Comment: You just beat me. I saw it too. Thanks!

Comment: Please select the answer as correct if it resolves your problem, so others will use it too. Thanks.